# Resize img content with css

Tags: html, css

I have `img` tag set with css:

```
.bakery-item > img {
    content: url('img/art-of-cakes-sprites.png');
    object-fit: none;
}
```

how can I then resize image just like I would with `background-size` property?

```
.bakery-item > img {
    width: 50%;
    /* resize image by 50% */
}
```

Image is a sprite so I dont want to use `cover`-like solution. I tried using `transform: scale(.5);` on element but this doesn't make element shrink in DOM (it still takes the same space).

I couldn't find anwser over the internet.

Answer (score 1):

This code sets the transform origin to the top left corner and scales to half size.

```
.bakery-item > img {
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer].

Comment: I already thought about it but this resizes the element while it still keeps the original space. So if `img` takes 400x400px then after scaling it will still take 400x400px.